# Validation rule, using ISNUMBER() for numbers

Tags: formula, validation

I am trying to add a new validation rule `ISNUMBER(number)` on a number type field.

but it seems like I couldn't because I got a syntax error, `Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNUMBER()'`

How could I validate this field and check if it's a number ?

Comment: What type is your "number" field?

Comment: It's a number type field.

Comment: Then why are you checking that it's a number?  It can only be a number.  ISNUMBER() requires a text field as its argument.  http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISNUMBER

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to perform this type of validation on a Number field. [`ISNUMBER`](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISNUMBER) simply:

> Determines if a **text value** is a number and returns TRUE if it is.
>   Otherwise, it returns FALSE.

It will only accept a **`TEXT` field** as a parameter.

This type of validation is not required. The Salesforce [Number](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/custom_field_types.htm) field will perform that validation innately. You do not need to do anything for that validation to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to determine whether the field has a value or not, then use ISBLANK(field__c), but if you just want to require a value, make the field required in the field definition.

Answer (score -1):

As said Nick Cook, you need to pass a textfield.

ISNUMBER('12345')    --> no error

ISNUMBER('Hell0 W0rld')  --> error

Answer (score -1):

NOT(ISNUMBER( Contract_ID__c ))

Comment: Can you provide more explanations about your answer please ?